# Calling Keras standard model preprocessing functions in TF Dataset pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am using some of the standard CNN models shipped with Keras as base for my own models - let's say a VGG16. Until now I am used to call the respective preprocessing functions via the Keras image data generators, like so:

```
ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=vgg16.preprocess_input)  # or any other std. model
```

Now I want to use a TF `Dataset` instead, so that I can use its `from_tensor_slices()` method, which makes multi GPU training easier. I came up with the following custom preprocessing function for this new pipeline:

```py
@tf.function
def load_images(image_path, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image)  # Is this call correct?
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return (image, label)
```

But I am not sure whether this is the correct order of function calls, as well as the correct place of calling `vgg16.preprocess_input(image)` within this order. Can I call this std. preprocessing function as this, or do I need to convert `image` data before/after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dataset `from_tensor_slices()` with your paths and labels and then use `map` to load and preprocess the images:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from PIL import Image

# Create random images
for i in range(3):
  imarray = numpy.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
  im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8'))
  im.save('result_image{}.jpeg'.format(i))

def load_images(image_path, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    
    #preprocess_input --> will convert the input images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling
    image = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    image /= 255.0 
    return image, label

IMG_SIZE = 64
paths = ['result_image0.jpeg', 'result_image1.jpeg', 'result_image2.jpeg']
labels = [0, 1, 1]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((paths, labels))
ds = dataset.map(load_images)

image, _ = next(iter(ds.take(1)))
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image]

Or you can use `tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` as part of your model. For example:

```
preprocess = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input

some_input = tf.keras.layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
some_output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(preprocess)(some_input)
model = tf.keras.Model(some_input, some_output)

model(tf.random.normal((2, 256, 256, 3)))
```

Comment: Why is the `image /= 250` necessary - isn't that already part of `vgg16.preprocess_input(image)`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://keras.io/api/applications/vgg/#vgg16-function), vgg16.preprocess_input will convert the input images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without *scaling*.

Comment: Ok I see, but why 250 but not 255? How about this line: `image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0`?

Comment: Sorry was a typo.